# Can we typecast a enum variable In c

Tags: c

I have been asked this question in interview:

> Is it possible to typecast a enum variable to some other type?

I really don't know how to answer it.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens ?

Comment: YES its good option @Paul let me try

Comment: `enum`s are 2nd rate types. They are effectively some kind of integer type. Anything you can cast an `int` to, you can also cast an `enum`. `enum x {A, B, C=42}; enum x someenum = 17; printf("%d %f\n", someenum, (double)someenum);`

Comment: I hope they haven't formulated it like that. In C you can't cast variables, only expressions.

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  In C `enum` types are just `int`s under the covers.  Typecast them to whatever you want.

```
enum cardsuit {
   Clubs = 1,
   Diamonds,
   Hearts,
   Spades
}; 
enum cardsuit trump = Diamonds;
int d = (int)trump;  /* 'd' would be 2 */
```

Comment: It doesn't even need the cast :-)

Comment: enums are not *always* ints in C.  However, it is reasonable to assume they are built on integral types.

Comment: @Throwback1986: C99 section 6.7.2.2 §2: "The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an int."; compilers are free to use a different integer type to represent the enumeration, but conversion to `int` is always lossless

Comment: @Christoph - exactly my point with the statement regarding integral types. To elaborate further, my current compiler (C99, embedded RTOS, ARM9) provides a --short-enum build setting that will generate one-byte or two-byte enums (as opposed to the four-byte enum that most directly maps to an int).

Answer (score 1):

Any `enum` expression in C can be converted to any arithmetic type, that are integers or floating points of any sort and pointers. E.g this is valid in C:

```
const enum { nullpointer } nullpointer_variable = nullpointer;

unsigned *p = nullpointer;           // initialization with an int
unsigned *p = nullpointer_variable;  // initialization with an enum expression
```

Most of the time you would not even need an explicit cast.